# Review my .htaccess I can't seem to make it work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please review my .htaccess code below. The code below was suggested by I User here (Thanks for the code Gumbo), And I can't seem to make it work.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /myadmin[/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^myadmin - [NC,L,R=404]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =myadmin.movietunie.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^myadmin/ /home/movietun/public_html/movie_tunie/myadmin/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

What I want to happen, In my domain (www.movietunie.com) I have a folder named (myadmin) and can be access by going to (www.movietunie.com/myadmin). Now there are a lot of user keep accessing that folder. I want to minimize it by changing the structure of it.

I want (myadmin) to be access in a subdomain structure instead of '/' so it would be something like this (myadmin.movietunie.com), Now when the try to access  (www.movietunie.com/myadmin) from a browser they will get an error, But the folder structure will still remain.

Hope this make sense

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you set up two [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/) for this purpose? Something like

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.movietunie.com
  ServerAlias movietunie.com
  DocumentRoot /home/movietun/public_html/movie_tunie/

  Redirect 301 /myadmin* http://myadmin.movietunie.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myadmin.movietunie.com
  DocumentRoot /home/movietun/public_html/movie_tunie/myadmin/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Zed,

But I don't know how it works and how can I implement it, Should I buy another server for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Added a tiny example of what your site's config file should look like.

Comment: I'll create httpd.conf for this right? in my /etc/httpd/conf/.  Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Umm, yes; but there should be other settings in your conf file, so be careful what you replace.

Comment: I still can access movietunie.com/myadmin. So here's what i've done in my (/etc) I created a folder (/httpd) and under it I created another folder of (/conf) and put httpd.conf containing only your code. I've notice in my (/etc) folder I got folders and they are named with my domains, Is that normal? I'm using shared hosting.

Comment: You should really read some docs on how Apache is configured in general.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^myadmin - [NC,L,R=404]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} myadmin.movietunie.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myadmin/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi Greg,

I updated my .htaccess and still can access my http://movietunie.com/myadmin/, Is there anything I should do aside from uploading my .htaccess?

Thanks!